# MIPS Instruction J-Format

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a question on the following MIPS code:
If the first instruction is placed in memory address at 0xFFFFFF00, what is the hexadecimal representation of the instruction "j loopEnd"?
I'm not sure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
loop:
    slt $t9, $s3, $s2   
    bne $t9, $zero, end
    add $s4, $s2, $s3           
    srl $s4, $s4, 1
    sll $t0, $s4, 2             
    add $t0, $s0, $t0       
    lw $t1, 0($t0)
    slt $t9, $s1, $t1       
    beq $t9, $zero, bigger  
    addi $s3, $s4, -1 
    j loopEnd
loopEnd:
    j loop
```

Comment: Why not just run `as` and then `objdump` to find out? Seems like the fastest and easiest way to me.

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure what you are referring to. I'm supposed to calculate it manually.

Comment: I'm referring to using an assembler and disassembler. Your question is unanswerable in its current state though, because there's no `loopEnd` in the code you pasted, which makes it impossible to calculate the branch target address.

Comment: oh, sorry, missed out the loopEnd code. have re-edited my qn.

Answer (score 8):

`j` is a j-type instruction and has the following format: `opcode - address`
which are 6 bits and 26 bits respectively.

The first 6 bits, the `opcode` for a `j` instruction is `000010`

The next 26 bits for the address are a bit trickier. First you will need the address of the label you are referring to. In your example, since the instruction address of `slt` is `0xFFFFFF00`, counting up by 4 everytime, the instruction address of  loopEnd (which is instruction `j loop`) will be `0xFFFFFF2C`.

So now we have the address of the target instruction `0xFFFFFF2C`, but this is 32 bits while we only have 26 bits to use for the target address in a J-type instruction. This is dealt with by dropping the first hex digit and dropping the last 2 binary digits. The first hex digit the address that will actually be jumped to will be the same as the current instruction (`F` in your case). We can drop the last 2 binary digits because instruction addresses are always multiples of 4, so we don't need the precision of 0, 1, 2, 3 that the last 2 binary digits give us, they will always be `00` for an instruction address.

Combining all this for your example:

`0xFFFFFF2C` -> `0x FFFFF2C` -> convert to binary

`1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_0010_1100` -> `1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_0010_10`

Now we combine the opcode with the interpreted instruction address:
`000010_11111111111111111111001010`

And that is the machine code for `j loopend`

TL;DR

1. Get opcode for the jump instruction
2. Get address at label in hex
3. Drop the first hex digit of address
4. Convert to binary
5. Drop the last two bits
6. Combine opcode and interpreted address